# Can I start a sentence/question with 'doesn't'?

Tags: questions, negation, auxiliary-verbs

For example,

> Doesn't he speak French?

or

> Doesn't she know common courtesy?

Comment: Good form to use. Use it to seek information: "Doesn't he speak French? I see. My mistake." Also, as a rhetorical question like the second example.

Comment: Yes. But I'm honestly confused by the question. Why wouldn't you be able to start a sentence with 'doesn't'?

Answer (score 2):

"Doesn't" is perfectly fine as a first word in a sentence.

I assume the main concern is that it's a contraction, and perhaps you're trying to apply the following principle:

> A sentence containing a contraction should make sense if and only if it makes sense if you expand the contraction in place.

This is fairly intuitive in many cases, e.g.:

> It's no secret that they're planning an event, but they can't find the resources.
>
> It is no secret that they are planning an event, but they cannot find the resources.

But the word order isn't right if you begin a sentence:

> Doesn't she know common courtesy?
>
> Does not she know common courtesy? (incorrect)
>
> Does she not know common courtesy? (correct)

...This is one of those cases where an exception is made in common English. In other words: the principle isn't absolute; sometimes the contraction is permitted even if expanding it would produce a reading with the wrong word order. And one of them involves beginning a sentence with a contraction. These are all fine:

> Isn't she lovely?
>
> Hasn't this been an issue for a while now?
>
> Doesn't this bother you?

It really does look a little weird... doesn't it?

Comment: In Jane Austen's _Emma_, Harriet says "Is not she very charming?". This kind of construction was quite correct in the past - I've seen it in other 19th century texts -  but nowadays if we wish to avoid using a contraction we prefer "Is she not..."